# Application of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions in $L^2[0,1]$ such that $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. If $\|f_n(x)\|_{L^2[0,1]}\le 1$ for all $n$ , then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)g(x)~dx =0$$ for all $g\in L^2[0,1]$.

I feel I have to use dominated convergence theorem, but I can't fined the dominating functions.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124736/a-question-on-convergence-in-lp/) for ideas.

Comment: My first instinct is to try applying Holder's inequality as $$\int_0^1 |f_n(x)g(x)|dx\leq \left(\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 |g(x)|dx\right)^{1/2}$$ but I'm not sure if $\|f_n\|_2$ can be effectively bounded.

Comment: The problem is the sequence $f_n$ just converges almost everywhere and do not necessarily converges to zero in norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an outline:

Fix $g\in L^2$.

Choose $\delta>0$ so that $\Bigl(\int_E|g|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}$ is small whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$.

By Egoroff, find a set $E$ of measure less than $\delta$ so that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ off $E$. Choose $N$ so that for $n>N$, $|f_n|$ is small on $E^C$.

Then write:
$$
\Bigl| \int f_n g\, \Bigr|\le \int |f_n ||g| =\int_E |f_n ||g|+\int_{E^C}|f_n ||g|
$$
and apply Hölder to both integrals on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply Egorov's theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure this works, because Egorov's leavues us with a set of $\epsilon>0$ measure left over and no bound on how $f_n$ behave on it.

Comment: We can perhaps estimate $\|f_n\|_{L^2(E)}$ where $E$ is the small set where the uniform convergence fails.

Comment: @matgaio Ah, I think I see it.