# if a sequence converges in measure in $L^p$, then converging for weak topology.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Given a finite measure space $(A,\Sigma,\mu)$, for $p \in (1,\infty)$,

if {$f_n$} is a bounded sequence in $L^p(A)$ converging in measure to $f \in L^p (A)$, then {$f_n$} converges to $f$ for the weak topology on $L^P(A)$.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/convergence-of-integrals-in-lp). Then show (by contradiction, e.g.) that convergence in measure suffices.