# Does convergence almost everywhere to an $L^p$ function and existence of a weakly convergent subsequence guarantee weak convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

By assumption, for $p \in (1,\infty)$, I have a bounded sequence of functions $f_n$ in $L^p$ (that is, $L^p$ norms of the functions are uniformly bounded) that converges almost everywhere to a function $f$.

With this, by boundedness and Fatou's lemma, one deduces $f\in L^p$. Additionally, since $L^p$ is a reflexive Banach space for our choice of $p$, we know that there exists a weakly convergent subsequence $f_{n_k} \xrightarrow{w} g$ in $L^p$, some $g\in L^p$. If I am able to show $f=g$ almost everywhere, is this enough to conclude that $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/convergence-of-integrals-in-lp) one way to solve your problem.

Comment: Great, thank you! Didn't mean for this to be a duplicate.

Comment: Note that the assumptions in the title of your question are different (weaker) than those in the question itself. With assumptions as in the title, your conclusion is not true.

Comment: Thanks, I know the bounded part is important for the result, I just didn't want to include more into the title.